# How to get the template argument of an alias-this-struct via is-expression in D?

Tags: templates, d, template-specialization

I was playing around with `alias this` which can simulate inheritance for structs in D. For a library that I recently started I also would like to provide trait templates which detect the proper type via `is`-expression.

Here is my type hierarchy.

```js
struct R(X) {
    S!X s;
    alias s this;
    
    this(X i) { s = i; }
}

struct S(X) {
    T a;
    alias T = X;
    alias a this;
    
    this(T t) { a = t; }
}

import std.stdio : writeln;
void main()
{
    R!int r = 3;
    S!int s = r;
    int i = r;
    writeln(r, " ", s, " ", i );
    
    static assert( is(r.s.T) && is(typeof(r) : S!(r.s.T)) );
    
    static assert( is(typeof(r) : R!X, X) );
    
    static assert( is(typeof(r) : int) && is(typeof(r) : S!int) );
    
    alias T = int;
    static assert( is(typeof(r) : S!T) );
    
    static assert(
        is(typeof(r) : S!Q, int Q) ||
        is(typeof(r) : S!Q, Q) ||
        is(typeof(r) : S!Q, r.s.T Q) ||
        is(typeof(r) : R!Q, int Q) ||
        is(typeof(r) : R!Q, r.s.T Q)
    );
}
```

I would expect all the `static asserts` to be true, so it is able to match a generic template argument via template specialization. But in reality, the last `static assert` is `false`! This is not just `rdmd` or `dmd` but also `ldc2`. I suppose, I made something wrong here.

My question is, how to extract the generic template argument `X` from type `S!X` properly without using an alias `r.s.T` from my example? I'd  like to do that via `is`-expression.

This question is specifically about `struct`. For performance and proramming experience, I will not use class inheritance instead of `alias this`. My struct will only be a small wrapper around a member field whose main purpose is overloading of some operators.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `is` INSIDE `static if` to do the extraction.

```
    static if(is(typeof(r) == R!Q, Q))
        pragma(msg, Q); // will print that int, you can just use Q as a type inside this branch
    else
        // not an instance of R
```

is(typeof(r) : R!Q, r.s.T Q) means the type of r implicitly casts to R!Q where Q is a value of type int. So that would be like R!4 or something. Same with the previous two and the first lines, they are looking for Q to be a value, not a type. Only the second item there is in the correct form to match this at all.... and I would guess it doesn't just because the compiler isn't smart enough to look that deep into it. Like a lot of is exprs realistically work best with one level of ask - implicit convert OR extract args. Here it asks to do both and tbh prolly a compiler bug / lazy impl.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that detail! I think, this isn't clear in D's language documentation and will help others.

I see, my question was imprecise. I mainly wonder why the last `static assert` in my code example is not working. Do you know why is that? And how can I make it work?

Is the compiler supposed to not pattern-match types of alias-this-members? I interprete the alias-this like a superclass and I thought ": Type" means that it can be implicitly type-casted to "Type".

Comment: `is(typeof(r) : R!Q, r.s.T Q)` means the type of r implicitly casts to R!Q where Q is a *value* of type `int`. So that would be like `R!4` or something. Same with the previous two and the first lines, they are looking for Q to be a value, not a type. Only the second item there is in the correct form to match this at all.... and I  would guess it doesn't just because the compiler isn't smart enough to look that deep into it. Like a lot of is exprs realistically work best with one level of ask - implicit convert OR extract args. Here it asks to do both and tbh prolly a compiler bug / lazy impl.

Comment: Thank you a lot !! That clarifies it. I just tried every combination I could think of^^. `alias-this` just isn't like an actual struct supertype, the compiler still seems to treat it different sometimes. I also noticed that structs with `alias-this` still need a type-cast to match a parametrized type variable.

Maybe you'd like to edit your post with your comment? Then I can accept your answer.

Comment: ok added to it. if you wanna learn more my D Cookbook from Packt has a page or two dedicated to the is expression too. Alas they no longer offer the free sample chapter so i can't link :(